# How do I install SQLite3 while setting up Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails for Windows 10.

I've tried several times to run the gem install bundler but there's always an error for SQLite3.

The command prompt says to install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ but I don't know where to place it in the directory.

I looked at the `mkmf.log` but I can't understand what it's telling me.

When I look in RailsInstaller's 'bin' folder sqlite3.def, sqlite 3.dll sqlite3 application and sqlite3_ruby (file and batch file) are present.

If anyone knows what might be going wrong and how to fix it I'd really appreciate some help, this problem never happens on the online how-to guides.

Many thanks

Command prompt message:

> An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source
>   'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
>
> In Gemfile:   sqlite3
>
> C:\Sites\test_app>gem install sqlite3 -v 1.4.0 Temporarily enhancing
>   PATH to include DevKit... Building native extensions.  This could take
>   a while... ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
> ```
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r
>   ./siteconf20190317-7152-n0tljg.rb extconf.rb checking for sqlite3.h...
>   no sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/
>   first.
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --without-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>           --with-sqlcipher
>           --without-sqlcipher
>           --with-sqlite3-config
>           --without-sqlite3-config
>           --with-pkg-config
>           --without-pkg-config
>           --with-sqlcipher
>           --without-sqlcipher
>           --with-sqlite3-dir
>           --without-sqlite3-dir
>           --with-sqlite3-include
>           --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
>           --with-sqlite3-lib
>           --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
>   which can be found here:
>
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.ou

Comment: Do you really ned the newest version of sqlite? I had also problems to install Version 1.4, but version 1.3.13 worked witout problems for me.

Comment: Thanks for answering - it says it installed okay but when I create a new Rails file it keeps trying to install sqlite3 1.4.0 instead... 1.3.13 is in C:\Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.5.0\gems, do I need to move it somewhere else?

Answer (score 7):

Rails tries to automatically install the latest version of the sqlite3 gem (1.4), but that new version doesn’t work with Rails yet. Specify a version that works like this:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'sqlite3', '< 1.4'
```

And re-run `bundle install`.

Comment: Thanks - word for word like C:\Users\Owner>gem 'sqlite3', '< 1.4'? I'm new to this so I'm not sure what an invalid command would look like. It comes up with 'The system cannot find the file specified' when I enter that or anything like it though. I also tried C:\Users\Owner>gem install sqlite3 1.3.13 but it seems to fail at 'missing function dlopen'.

Comment: @SJM1 No. In your Rails application directory, there's a file named `Gemfile`. Open that file and update the line that currently says `gem 'sqlite3'` to the above, which specifies the version to install. Then save that file and run `bundle install` on the command line while in the same directory as the `Gemfile`.

Comment: I opened it with wordpad (there were lots of files called Gemfile, only one with that line) and updated it, but I'm not sure if I ran the bundle install file correctly. When you say while in the same directory as the Gemfile do you mean in the folder or in the command prompt? It's still trying to install 1.40.

Comment: @SJM1 `bundle install` would be called from the command prompt, as in `cd c:\path\to\your\rails\app && bundle install`.

Comment: Hmmm it can't find it, I might have to find someone who can go through it with me in person. Thanks for all the help though @Unixmonkey

Comment: Thank you so much. Been struggling with this for too long and finally solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Open the Gemfile that is inside your project folder and change the line gem 'sqlite3' to gem 'sqlite3', '< 1.4' like suggested by @Unixmonkey

From
`gem 'sqlite3'`
to `gem 'sqlite3', '< 1.4'`

Answer (score 0):

1. don't run your code on windows
2. if you really have to, use gem 1.3.13

```
gem install sqlite3 -v 1.3.13
```

this will not install native extensions for windows. thus won't cause any error.