# Ruby on rails : problem of verifiying the SSL certificate while installing bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm new with ruby on rails and while creating my first project with this command `rails new n_project`, i got this error

```
run  bundle install
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see .... To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see .... To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see .... To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most
likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
information about OpenSSL certificates, see ...
```

I tried changing https to http in Gemfile and execute only `bundle install` but the problem wasn't solved . This message appears instead:

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.
Retrying dependency api due to error (2/4): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://index.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails%2Csqlite3%2Cpuma%2Csass-rails%2Cuglifier%2Ccoffee-rails%2Cjquery-rails%2Cturbolinks%2Cjbuilder%2Cbyebug%2Cweb-console%2Ctzinfo-data.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see .... To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
Retrying dependency api due to error (3/4): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://index.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails%2Csqlite3%2Cpuma%2Csass-rails%2Cuglifier%2Ccoffee-rails%2Cjquery-rails%2Cturbolinks%2Cjbuilder%2Cbyebug%2Cweb-console%2Ctzinfo-data.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see .... To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
Retrying dependency api due to error (4/4): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://index.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails%2Csqlite3%2Cpuma%2Csass-rails%2Cuglifier%2Ccoffee-rails%2Cjquery-rails%2Cturbolinks%2Cjbuilder%2Cbyebug%2Cweb-console%2Ctzinfo-data.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see .... To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
```

Answer (score 8):

Your question came up when I was googling for an answer to the same problem. I had just create a new rails project and it gave error.

```
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb
         run  bundle install
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.o
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed forormation about OpenSSL certificates, see bitlylink. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https
Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.o
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed forormation about OpenSSL certificates, see bitlylink. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https
Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.o
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed forormation about OpenSSL certificates, see bitlylink. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https
Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most
likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
information about OpenSSL certificates, see bitlylink. To connect
without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
```

Hopefully you managed to solve your problem but I thought I would describe the steps that solved it for me in case others have the same problem.

This solution is for Windows 10, Ruby 2.3.3, Rails 5.1 and Git-Bash.

I followed this guide.
https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html#automated-ssl-check

Hopefully any future changes and solutions to SSL cert issues are updated in this guide.

First of all. Editing the Gemfile and changing

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

did not work at all.

So according to the guide:

Step 1. run

```
curl -Lks 'https://git.io/rg-ssl' | ruby
```

This just showed me that I could not connect via SSL so not particulary helpful.

Step 2. update bundler

```
gem install bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (httppecs.4.8.gz)
```

This also failed because of SSL error.

Step 3. update Rubygems.

```
gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

This also failed.

Step 4. update system clock.
Yeah no, I'm on windows so not doing this.

---

***Here is where things start working towards solution:***

Step 5. Update CA certificates. Guide wants me to download a certificate file.

```
Download the .pem file from this link:  GlobalSignRootCA.pem
```

Use the actual guide to find **latest** link to certificate. I download the certificate file.

Step 5.1. Find RubyGems certificate directory in your installation

```
gem which rubygems
```

For me the directory was 'C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\lib\ruby\2.3.0\rubygems\ssl_certs'

Step 5.2. I copy the GlobalSignRootCA_R3.pem file into this directory.

After doing this I should according to guide

> follow the directions at the very top to automatically update RubyGems.

Step 5.3. So with certificate file in the directory I run

```
gem update --system
ERROR:  Interrupted
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-3.2.15
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.2.15
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-update-3.2.15
```

This takes forever without any user feedback so I interrupt terminal. But it appears to have been doing some work.

Step 5.4. I then try to run bundle install to download and install dependencies.

```
bundle install
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Could not verify the SSL certificate for
https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-5.1.7.gemspec.rz.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most
likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
information about OpenSSL certificates, see a bitly link. To connect
without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
```

But I still get some SSL cert error.

Step 5.5.  However the guide specifically mentions that bundler itself should be updated. So I do that with

```
gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-2.2.15
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.2.15
Installing ri documentation for bundler-2.2.15
Done installing documentation for bundler after 21 seconds
1 gem installed
```

And bundler updates successfully.

Step 5.6. Finally I run bundle install again which now starts downloading and installing dependencies without any ssl error.

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Resolving dependencies......
Fetching rake 13.0.3
Installing rake 13.0.3
Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Fetching i18n 1.8.9
Installing i18n 1.8.9
Fetching minitest 5.14.4
Installing minitest 5.14.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Fetching tzinfo 1.2.9
... and so on
```

Extra: Installing gave an sqlite3 error which was solved with info found here. [How do I install SQLite3 while setting up Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208638/how-do-i-install-sqlite3-while-setting-up-ruby-on-rails)

After all that. It is up and running.

```
$ rails server
   => Booting Puma
   => Rails 5.1.7 application starting in development
   => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
   *** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
   *** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
   *** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
   Puma starting in single mode...
   * Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
   * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
   * Environment: development
   * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
```

Comment: For me, the directory was C:\Ruby25-x64\ssl\certs (and then running the `c_rehash.rb` script that was in the directory).

Comment: Step 1 indicated the missing certificate in the openssl gem's bundle. So I added my proxy certificate to the bottom of `$HOME/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/openssl/ssl/cert.pem` and that solved it.